# Brightness problem with Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, brightness

I use Xubuntu Linux

Brightness is good without using suspend mode but after using suspend mode I got problem with brightness 
It's lower than before !
I need your help

Comment: Do you have brightness keys like on most laptops? Have you tried adjusting it back up with those?

Comment: Brightness keys don't work after using suspend mode !!

Comment: What model & make of laptop?

Comment: Toshiba Satellite A300-15C 
http://eu.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/jsp/SUPPORTSECTION/discontinuedProductPage.do?service=EU&com.broadvision.session.new=Yes&PRODUCT_ID=150523

Answer (score 3):

http://www.iasptk.com/save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-1204-laptop

Some Ubuntu laptops screen brightness reset to the lowest or highest on every boot and you have to configure the screen birghtness on every login.

To save the screen brightness settings in Ubuntu laptop.

Open a terminal window, and execute this command to edit /etc/rc.local:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

**Add this before the last line “exit 0″:**

```
echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

number 5 is the value of your screen brightness. With this command check the maximum:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

Answer (score 1):

My m6700 use the disk from another PC, which has xubuntu 12.04.

I had the same problem then I downloaded the kernel from

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git
```

and compiled using the command:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --revision 00.m6700 --initrd --append-to-version=-localmod  kernel-image kernel-headers
```

and then installed the generated packages by the command `dpkg -i *.deb`, then after a reboot the problem was solved.

The Git branch I checkout out was:

- Commit 35fd156f210074f981de9963ecd07fb3630e072d
- Author: Brad Figg
- Date:   Tue Dec 3 08:37:09 2013 -0800

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your /etc/default/grub file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

To: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Or: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight