# Xubuntu 12.10 doesn't save screen brightness on reboot

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, acpi

I have a laptop running Xubuntu 12.10 that doesn't save the brightness setting on reboot. There are some explanations on Ask Ubuntu about how to have a *specific* brightness be set on reboot, but not how to *save* the brightness from last time. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Bash script to save the brightness:

```
sudo nano /etc/acpi/save-brightness.sh
```

It should contain this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Saves brightness settings on reboot/shutdown

cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness > /etc/acpi/brightness
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/save-brightness.sh
```

Switch to the `/etc/rc0.d` directory and symlink the script to a link in `/etc/rc0.d`:

```
cd /etc/rc0.d
sudo ln -s ../acpi/save-brightness.sh K99-save-brightness
```

Do this again in the `/etc/rc6.d` directory (`rc0` is for reboots and `rc6` is for shutdowns).

Now edit `/etc/rc.local` to reload the brightness setting on boot.

On a separate line just before the last line that's already there (`exit 0`), put:

```
cat /etc/acpi/brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Sources:

[1] http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown

[2] https://askubuntu.com/a/189485/30117